# Certain special characters after < breaks link text

Tags: bug, formatting, magic-links

When I was trying to link an answer in an answer I was posting which included `<?=` and I included `<?=` in the link display text, it would not render correctly.

**Raw Formatting**

```
[Is it bad practice to use <?= tag in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)
```

**Formatted Output**

Is it bad practice to use

**Update #1**

The above formatting works in the comments.

Comment: [Is it bad practice to use <?= tag in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)

Comment: It seems to work in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use code markdown around the `<` to prevent it being interpreted as the start of an html tag.

[Is it bad practice to use `<?=` tag in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)

> ```
>  [Is it bad practice to use `<?=` tag in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)
> ```

Or go HTML all the way:

[Is it bad practice to use <?= tag in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)

> ```
> <a href="https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php">Is it bad practice to use &lt;?= tag in PHP?</a>
> ```

Yes, all very hacky. But hey, It Works™ ...

Comment: Sure, this works but it seems odd that we have to surround it with back ticks. Seems hacky.

Comment: Well, as it is also allowed to use regular html in posts the markdown parser has to stop somewhere and assume *normal* html will follow. I guess this is status-bydesign but maybe this bug report pushes it enough so the next version of the  parser will recognize if there is a valid html tag following a < and if not will continue to assume markdown was meant. We'll see in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: '*We'll see in 6 to 8 weeks*' after the completion of all the updates for careers and teams.